# Android Google+ sign in with WebView

Tags: java, android, google-plus

I have to implement Google+ sign in through a Android `WebView` and get user profile information. I have searched so many links and tutorials but found nothing helpful. Please suggest or share any helpful links or tutorials.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in a web view on Android? Have you seen this? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/

Comment: I want that user can sign in from any google account but if i use google sdk then user can use only existing android google account

Comment: @ajay not only existing google account, new google sdk supporting multiple login.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Google sdk api,

and remember new google sdk supporting multiple login.

check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported anymore:

[Modernizing OAuth interactions in Native Apps for Better Usability and Security](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html)

[Google to block web views from using its OAuth](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/08/23/google_to_block_web_views_from_using_its_oauth/)